# error: request for member ‘portD’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct, scanf

Estoy tratando de acceder a un miembro que existe en una estructura bien definida, pero estoy teniendo ese error. Es un programa que hace ciertas operaciones con puertos en un microcontrolador.

Cuando pongo este codigo, el error no aparece y funciona correctamente. Los parametros de la funcion `port_operations` son correctos y esa funcion hace lo que debe sin errores:

```
port_operations(1, 'A', 5);
printf ("%X\n", p.portD.W);
```

Pero con este codigo si aparece el error `request for member ‘portD’ in something not a structure or union`:

```
int o;
char p;
int d;
scanf ("%d %c %d", &o, &p, &d);
port_operations(1, 'A', 5);
printf ("%X\n", p.portD.W);
```

El error aparece incluso al no estar usando `o, p y d`como parametros para `port_operations`.

Alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo?
Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu declaracion que `p` es un `char` sombrea estructura. Da otro nombre a esa variable.

Comment: Gracias!! Se ve que cuando uno ya lleva dias y dias haciendo lo mismo en algun momento termina cansado... Muchas gracias!